# Disable external service Android

Tags: android, android-service, samsung-mobile, samsung-knox

I need to disable programmatically trough my app some Samsung services which came active by default on my phone (S6). I only know their package name. This option have to be possible to execute on non-rooted devices. I saw some apps at Play Store like "Package disabler pro" which allow to do that, so it is possible, but after looking for some info I don't know how to do it. Any idea?

Edit: I have seen that "Package disabler pro" only works for Samsung devices, it might be the key of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only way to do it is by using Samsung KNOX SDK if we are not root users.